# how to clear selected checkboxes programatically from parent component

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, multi-select

I have used the following component in react,
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-multiselect-checkboxes

I want to clear selected checkboxes because I have to recreate it with new options from another dropdown change event.

So is there any way from where I can clear selected checkboxes from parent component when another dropdown is changed

This is for react

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

The author of the libarary suggest that its behavior is based on `react-select`

Have you tried to use value prop?

see https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select#controllable-props

Additionally if you want to manipulate values in parent component you should use onChange callback then and store it somewhere (I assume state will be best place)

Comment: Yes, I tried but since React is re-rendering everytime if any checkbox is selected or on any parent component value changed, we can't set value/defaultValue.